# Definition of "static type" and "dynamic type"

Tags: c++

I'm a little confused about the terms "static type" and "dynamic type".

Given

```
class A {};
class B:A {};

A* a = new B();
B* b = new B();
```

The static type of *a is B and the dynamic type is A.
The static type of *b is B and the dynamic type is B.

Is that correct?

This is not a question about dynamic type checking but rather the terms "static type" and "dynamic type". In this article http://makomdev.blogspot.com/2008/04/c-static-types-vs-dynamic-types.html the author defines static type as the "real" type and dynamic type as the base type.
He also defines them in terms of rhs and lhs which seems contradictory.

Comment: did you mean the type of `*a` ?

Comment: I'm not asking about dynamic type checking but rather the terms "static type" and "dynamic type". In this article http://makomdev.blogspot.com/2008/04/c-static-types-vs-dynamic-types.html this guy defines static type as the "real" type and dynamic type as the base type. He also talks about them in terms of rhs and lhs which seems contradictory.

Comment: I just added an answer to the "duplicate" question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16571767/37386