# Run-time type information in C++

Tags: c++, rtti

What is runtime type control in C++?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351845/finding-the-type-of-an-object-in-c/351865#351865  have a look at this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It enables you to identify the dynamic type of a object at run time. For example:

```
class A
{
   virtual ~A();
};

class B : public A
{
}

void f(A* p)
{
  //b will be non-NULL only if dynamic_cast succeeds
  B* b = dynamic_cast<B*>(p);
  if(b) //Type of the object is B
  {
  }
  else //type is A
  { 
  }
}

int main()
{
  A a;
  B b;

  f(&a);
  f(&b);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It is not just about dynamic_cast, but the entire RTTI is part of it. The best place to learn about RTTI is section 15.4 of the [C++ Programming Language](https://web.archive.org/web/20090919000207/http://www.research.att.com:80/%7Ebs/3rd.html) by Bjarne Stroustrup

Answer (score 2):

It's `dynamic_cast` functionality - your code can detect at runtime if a given pointer or reference is really bound to an object of type you expect.

Answer (score 2):

The correct name of this is [Run-time type information (RTTI)](http://google.com/search?q=rtti).

Comment: +1 I have never seen "lmgtfy" before =) Great resource, really =)

Comment: Please explain the downvotes made to this post. Downvoting without comments is not fair.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a Interface* and "ask" c++ to what type of object the pointer points.
To my knowledge, this relies on runtime meta information, that needs a few cycles
for storing and searching such information.

Look at the "typeid" keyword. It provides the most magic.

dynamic_cast only *uses* RTTI, *typeid* with std::type_info 
seems to me more like the "real thing".