# 'typeid' versus 'typeof' in C++

Tags: c++, typeof, typeid

I am wondering what the difference is between `typeid` and `typeof` in C++. Here's what I know:

- `typeid` is mentioned in the documentation for  [type_info](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/typeinfo/type_info/) which is defined in the C++ header file [typeinfo](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/typeinfo/?kw=typeinfo).
- `typeof` is defined in the GCC extension for C and in the C++ [Boost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_C%2B%2B_Libraries) library.

Also, here is test code test that I've created where I've discovered that `typeid` does not return what I expected. Why?

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <typeinfo>  //for 'typeid' to work  

class Person {  
    public:
    // ... Person members ...  
    virtual ~Person() {}  
};  

class Employee : public Person {  
    // ... Employee members ...  
};  

int main () {  
    Person person;  
    Employee employee;  
    Person *ptr = &employee;  
    int t = 3;  

    std::cout << typeid(t).name() << std::endl;  
    std::cout << typeid(person).name() << std::endl;   // Person (statically known at compile-time)  
    std::cout << typeid(employee).name() << std::endl; // Employee (statically known at compile-time)  
    std::cout << typeid(ptr).name() << std::endl;      // Person * (statically known at compile-time)  
    std::cout << typeid(*ptr).name() << std::endl;     // Employee (looked up dynamically at run-time  
                                                       // because it is the dereference of a pointer
                                                       // to a polymorphic class)  
 }
```

**output:**

```
bash-3.2$ g++ -Wall main.cpp -o main  
bash-3.2$ ./main   
i  
6Person  
8Employee  
P6Person  
8Employee
```

Comment: In what way do you think your code doesn't print the right type names? It looks good to me. The actual string returned by `name()` is implementation-defined. It doesn't have to be a valid C++ identifier name, just *something* that uniquely identifies the type. Looks like your implementation uses the compiler's general name-mangling scheme.

Comment: Thanks Rob! I was expecting those exactly same as type names as I saw in en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeid. What can name-mangling do here?

Comment: If you are new to typeid like me: You need a virtual function in the base type to turn on the vtable or the last line will print the base type.

Answer (score 258, accepted):

C++ language has no such thing as `typeof`. You must be looking at some compiler-specific extension. If you are talking about GCC's `typeof`, then a similar feature is present in C++11 through the keyword `decltype`. Again, C++ has no such `typeof` keyword.

`typeid` is a C++ language operator which returns type identification information at run time. It basically returns a `type_info` object, which is equality-comparable with other `type_info` objects.

Note, that the only defined property of the returned `type_info` object has is its being equality- and non-equality-comparable, i.e. `type_info` objects describing different types shall compare non-equal, while `type_info` objects describing the same type have to compare equal. Everything else is implementation-defined. Methods that return various "names" are not guaranteed to return anything human-readable, and even not guaranteed to return anything at all.

Note also, that the above probably implies (although the standard doesn't seem to mention it explicitly) that consecutive applications of `typeid` to the same type might return different `type_info` objects (which, of course, still have to compare equal).

Comment: wouldnt this need an update since C++11 has `decltype` ? I am not sure what is the general policy, but as the question is tagged `C++` I would expect it to refer to the latest standard. Retagging the question as `C++03` would also be an option imho. I personally get quite confused sometimes, as I have to use preC++11 at work and sometimes I am not sure what is true "pre11" or "post11".

Comment: FYI, `decltype` is not a replacement for `typeof`. `typeof` works on types too while `decltype` doesn't. For example, `typeof(int)` is `int` while `decltype(int)` is an error.

Comment: *"`type_info` objects describing different types shall compare non-equal"*. Actually, this [isn't guaranteed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/hash_code). The inequality operator was [removed in C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/operator_cmp) to (I assume) discourage relying on different types comparing non-equal. But if you think about it, equality isn't safe if inequality isn't safe.

Comment: @IndianaKernick Your link points to hash_code, which is unrelated to equality because hash functions do not have to guarantee to be free of collisions to be useful.

Comment: @Shahbaz I found another difference: `decltype` will preserve reference types while `typeof` will remove them. For example, with `int& x;`, `typeof(x)` will give `int` while `decltype(x)` will give `int&`. I found this thread while searching why `typeof` seemed to cast away reference types.

Answer (score 63):

The primary difference between the two is the following

- typeof is a compile time construct and returns the type as defined at compile time
- typeid is a runtime construct and hence gives information about the runtime type of the value.

typeof Reference: http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gcc/gcc_36.html

typeid Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeid

Comment: Thank you, JaredPar! I have some new questions in the updated post after reading your replies. Such as if it is also true that their returns are used for different purposes: the return of typeof is used as type keyword that can define variable, but the return of typeid cannot?

Comment: first link is no longer working ( send to http://www.gnu.org/ ).

Answer (score 28):

[`typeid`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeid) can operate at runtime, and return an object describing the run time type of the object, which must be a pointer to an object of a class with virtual methods in order for [RTTI (run-time type information)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) to be stored in the class. It can also give the compile time type of an expression or a type name, if not given a pointer to a class with run-time type information.

[`typeof`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html) is a GNU extension, and gives you the type of any expression at compile time. This can be useful, for instance, in declaring temporary variables in macros that may be used on multiple types. In C++, you would usually use [templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_(programming)) instead.

Comment: As far as I know, `typeid` will accept any expression, not just those that evaluate to objects with virtual methods. Furthermore, `typeid` will accept a type *name*, not just an expression. You can say `typeid(5)` or `typeid(std::string)` if you want.

Comment: I've clarified my answer to make that clear; `typeid` *can* return run-time type information if available, but will provide compile time type information for anything else.

Comment: Thank you, Brian and Rob! I have some new questions in the updated post after reading your replies.

Answer (score 27):

Answering the additional question:

> my following test code for typeid does
>   not output the correct type name.
>   what's wrong?

There isn't anything wrong. What you see is the string representation of the type name. The standard C++ doesn't force compilers to emit the exact name of the class, it is just up to the implementer(compiler vendor) to decide what is suitable. In short, the names are up to the compiler.

---

These are two different tools. `typeof` returns the type of an expression, but it is not standard. In C++0x there is something called `decltype` which does the same job AFAIK.

```
decltype(0xdeedbeef) number = 0; // number is of type int!
decltype(someArray[0]) element = someArray[0];
```

Whereas `typeid` is used with polymorphic types. For example, lets say that `cat` derives `animal`:

```
animal* a = new cat; // animal has to have at least one virtual function
...
if( typeid(*a) == typeid(cat) )
{
    // the object is of type cat! but the pointer is base pointer.
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Arak! I just updated the post with some new questions. Please take a look if possible.

Answer (score 5):

typeid provides the type of the data at runtime, when asked for. Typedef is a compile time construct that defines a new type as stated after that. There is no typeof in C++
Output appears as (shown as inscribed comments):

```
std::cout << typeid(t).name() << std::endl;  // i
std::cout << typeid(person).name() << std::endl;   // 6Person
std::cout << typeid(employee).name() << std::endl; // 8Employee
std::cout << typeid(ptr).name() << std::endl;      // P6Person
std::cout << typeid(*ptr).name() << std::endl;     //8Employee
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Boost demangle to accomplish a nice looking name:

```
#include <boost/units/detail/utility.hpp>
```

and something like

```
To_main_msg_evt ev("Failed to initialize cards in " + boost::units::detail::demangle(typeid(*_IO_card.get()).name()) + ".\n", true, this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Although as top commenter pointed out, there is no such thing as typeof in C++, you can leverage function overloads to make a faux typeof function:

```
const char *type_of(int x){return “int”;}
const char *type_of(const char *x){return “const char*”;}
```

Of course, this is could be extended upon to also use other data types. I’m newer to C++, so there may be some issues with it, such as errors at runtime, however in my use case of using template params and descerning an int from a float, for example, was straightforward.

Optimizations: It would probably be better for the overloaded function to return a short as opposed to const char *’s for the sake of memory efficiency, which then could be compared to another short, or plugged into a hash table for the string representation.

Comment: Not correct. There's a [GNU extension which provides `typeof`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html) and standard C++ has `__typeof__` and [`typeid`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid)

Comment: Problem is…what it produces is often not descriptive enough. typeid(int) returns “i”