# How to find out the type of a variable, with inheritance/polymorphism involved

Tags: c++, inheritance, types

How do I find out the type of a variable when inheritance is involved?

I'm having a little situation, I'll describe it in pseudocode:

```
class A
{
public:
A();
virtual ~A();

protected:
//some members
};

class B : public A
{
public:
B();
virtual ~B();

protected:
//some members
};
```

///////////////////////

```
int main()
{
A* pA = new B();
std::cout<<"type of pA: "<< ???;
}
```

How can I find out the type of pA? the result should be B. Also, what should I do if I want the result to be A?

Thanks.

---

### EDIT:

I'll let you be the judge of whether it is bad design or not. If you think it is, then please tell me a better alternative.

Code:

```
class MyContactReport : public NxUserContactReport
{
    void OnContactNotify(NxContactPair& pair, NxU32 events)
    {
        if (pair.actors[0]->userData == NULL || pair.actors[1]->userData == NULL) return;

        LevelElement* otherObject = (LevelElement*)pair.actors[1]->userData;
        LevelElement* triggerObject = (LevelElement*)pair.actors[0]->userData;

        switch(events)
        {
        case NX_NOTIFY_ON_START_TOUCH:
            triggerObject->OnContactStartTouch(otherObject);
            break;
        case NX_NOTIFY_ON_END_TOUCH :
            triggerObject->OnContactEndTouch(otherObject);
            break;
        case NX_NOTIFY_ON_TOUCH:
            triggerObject->OnContactTouch(otherObject);
            break;
        }
    }
} *myReport;
```

`pair.actors[1]->userData` gives me access to the userData from an actor, an actor is something of the PhysX framework, that determines collisions and physics etc. The userdata is of type `void*`.
This is also the only way to find out object the actor actually belongs to.

Then there's `class LevelElement`, an abstract class where every object in my level inherits from (level as in a game-level)

LevelElement has protected virtual methods: `OnContactTouch(LevelElement* pOtherElement)` etc...
In those methods, I need to find out what type of LevelElement it is, to take certain specific measures.

Is this bad design? If yes, please help!

Comment: Why do you care? Your code should not make decisions based on the runtime type of an object. Your objects should be able to do the job of an A via the interface that A provides, objects of type B will implement the interface in a specific way.

Comment: One reason could be for example for logging.

Comment: @LokiAstari Because I'm working with frameworks that require this kind of information. I'll update the question to provide that information.

Comment: The simple fact is that if you need different actions per type then you're misusing polymorphism.

Comment: @ildjarn I don't exactly gain much reading statements without an explanation. I thought that was the reason why polymorphism was invented in the first place. And that's what I've been taught anyway.

Comment: I made a comment instead of an answer because I didn't have time to explain further. :-]

Comment: @xcrypt: Then you have misunderstood what you were taught. Polymorhism allows different types to do different things **without the user knowing the type**. If you are do doing different things based on the type at the use point you are not using polymorphism. The whole idea is that the object knows what to do just ask it to do the task then each different type will do the correct action.

Comment: In the method: `OnContactTouch(LevelElement* pOtherElement)` don't do actions based on the type of `pOtherElement` you ask `pOtherElement` to do things to you. ie `OnContactTouch(LevelElement* pOtherElement) {return pOtherElement->hasBeenTouched(this);}`

Comment: @LokiAstari I'm pretty sure I haven't misunderstood what I've been taught, but maybe I've been taught wrong then. Anyway, you can't assume that it's all I'm doing with the LevelElement class. I am also doing stuff where the user doesn't know the type with it. And something like `OnContactTouch(LevelElement* pOtherElement) {return pOtherElement->hasBeenTouched(this);}` wouldn't work in this case, because there's too much variety in all the classes that inherit from LevelElement, and too many different behaviours. I would also have to check type in `pOtherElement->hasBeenTouched(this);` then.

Comment: @LokiAstari But I must thank you for clarifying the goals of polymorphism.

Comment: "*there's too much variety in all the classes that inherit from LevelElement, and too many different behaviours*" **This** is the indication that you're misusing polymorphism. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn I do need polymorphism for the reasons mentioned by Loki, too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the typeid operator, as described for example [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fthe_typeid_operator.htm).

Basically:

```
#include <typeinfo>
```

[...]

```
std::cout << "typeid(*pA): " << typeid(*pA).name() << std::endl;
std::cout << "typeid(pA): " << typeid(pA).name() << std::endl;
```

Results, with g++ 4.4.5:

```
typeid(*pA): 1B
typeid(pA): P1A
```

I.e. there is some mangling involved at least using gcc.  Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789402/typeid-returns-extra-characters-in-g) for how to deal with this.

---

EDIT: As for your design question, instead of checking what type the otherObject is, a better solution is to just tell this object what to do.  Assuming you want to code the onContactTouch for a hypothetical Bullet object; instead of

```
switch (type) {
case PLAYER:
    (Player*)otherObject->dealDamage(10);
    break;
case BULLETPROOF_GLASS:
    (BulletproofGlass*)otherObject->ricochet();
    break;
}
```

do this:

```
otherObject->onHitByBullet(this);
```

This is sometimes called the [tell, don't ask](http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask) principle.

Comment: `typeid(pA)` should be `A*`; the type of the object is not `A`, so that would be wrong anyway.

Comment: It should be added that it's usually a  "smell" that it's a bad design if you need to determine the type of an object at runtime.

Comment: In any case, to use typeid() you need to have turned RTTI on in your compiler settings. A more detailed discussion about RTTI can be found here: [RTTI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438678/using-typeid-for-simple-decisions)

Comment: @nyarlathotep please come up with an alternative if you say things like that. I have updated the question to give you more information

Comment: I know it's much better to "tell, not ask", but in this case it's weird to do it like your example. The problem here is that certain I cannot make a base class virtual method ->onHitByBullet(this) because it doesn't apply to all LevelElements. And if I'd make base class virtual methods like that for every LevelElements, I would end up with like 500 methods or something.

I always prefer to write code that "tells", but sometimes it's hard to find a good design pattern.

Comment: @xcrypt: Indeed, it's hard to know without having all the details.  As long as you know your options you should choose the method that works best in your case.

Answer (score 1):

This is not strictly a symptom of bad design. Although you certainly could abstract the types out of the type checking. For the sake of performance and runtime customization, you should almost definitely NOT use RTTI or other direct type checking systems. Implementing your own (much simplified) type checking dynamic allows objects to define collision behavior at an object level rather than a class level and to redefine collision behavior at runtime.

```
//PSEUDO CODE
enum CollisionTypes = {HARD_THING, SOFT_THING, EXPLODING_THING};

class FragileThing is a GameObject
{
    public function getCollisionType()
    {
        return SOFT_THING;
    }
    public function collideWith(GameObject obj)
    {
        if (obj.getCollisionType() == SOFT_THING)
            print "whew...";
        else
            print "OUCH!";
    }
}

class CollisionDispatcher is a PhysXCollisionListener
{
    public function getCollisionFromPhysX(Collision col)
    {
        col.left.collideWith(col.right);
        col.right.collideWith(col.left);
    }
}
```

Another system that I have seen used (in books) is to use an engine wide messaging framework to dispatch collisions with type information embedded into the message. Unrelated types can simply ignore the messages. I have not tried this though. I would also recommend examining your LevelObject class to determine if there isn't some kind of common functionality you can add to it that would sidestep this problem. For instance, if there are very few fundamental types of objects (Red and Green perhaps, or Ethereal, Soft, Hard, Explosive) then you can, instead of conditional statements, encode those types into function calls: `function collideWithSomethingHard(LevelObject obj)` thus allowing objects to define only the collision behavior they care about. Hope this helps a little.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do that, then most likely your interface is lacking or designed sub-optimally. Instead revisit your interface and provide an appropriate set of (possibly abstract) virtual methods to implement your required interface. Then you won't need to worry about specific subypes.

If you *really* need the information you can use `typeid` as seen in the answer from @Emil Styrke

Answer (score 0):

When you use the function `typeid(pA).name()`  .  The result is `class A *`.

```
// typeid
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
        A(){}
        virtual ~A(){}

    protected:

};

class B : public A
{
    public:
        B(){}
        virtual ~B(){}

    protected:

};


int main()
{
A* pA = new B();

   cout<<"The expression [A* pA = new B()]: \n";
   cout<<"Has datatype --> "<< typeid(pA).name()  <<"<-- \n";
   cout<<" \n";

   return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
The expression [A* pA = new B()]:
Has datatype --> class A *<--

Press any key to continue
```