# Why C++ doesn't allow me to use typeof?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

I'm using following code with C++11 and getting a error that I'm not allowed to use `typeof` !

What is the problem and how to fix this ?

The error :

```
Error   10  error C2923: 'typeof' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'C'
```

Here is my code :

```
#define HIBERLITE_NVP(Field) hiberlite::sql_nvp< typeof(Field) >(#Field,Field)


class Person{
friend class hiberlite::access;
template<class Archive>
void hibernate(Archive & ar)
{
    ar & HIBERLITE_NVP(name); //ERROR
    ar & HIBERLITE_NVP(age);  //ERROR
    ar & HIBERLITE_NVP(bio);  //ERROR
}
public:
string name;
double age;
vector<string> bio;
};
```

sql_nvp is like this :

```
template<class C>
 class sql_nvp{
public:
    std::string name;
    C& value;
    std::string search_key;

    sql_nvp(std::string _name, C& _value, std::string search="") :    name(_name), value(_value), search_key(search) {}
 };
```

Comment: How about "C++ doesn't have `typeof`"?

Comment: Use `decltype` instead.

Comment: Alternatively, you could write a function template which can infer the type, e.g. `make_nvp(#Field,Field)`. This will also work in older versions of the language without `decltype`.

Comment: Agree with @MikeSeymour. To clarify: class templates do not have Template Argument Deduction, which is why the standard has a `std::make_pair<T,U>(T, U)` to create a `std::pair<T,U>`. Clearly, `make_nvp<Field>` would be a template function that returns a `sql_nvp<Field>`, using Template Argument Deduction to figure out the `Field` type.

Comment: In defence of OP a lot of compilers had typeof with variable semantic, some with underscores, etc.  Hence the start-over with decltype.  Plus Javascript, C# spell it this way.

Comment: technically, `typeid` in C++ is more like `typeof` operator found in other languages like C# but certainly here the author was looking for `decltype`

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986418/typeid-and-typeof-in-c

Answer (score 32, accepted):

What you are looking for is `decltype()`:

```
#define HIBERLITE_NVP(Field) hiberlite::sql_nvp< decltype(Field) >(#Field,Field)
//                                               ^^^^^^^^
```

C++ does not have an operator called `typeof`.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that there are/were differences between `typeof` and `decltype`. Depending on which compiler and version provided `typeof(X)`, it is more like `std::decay<decltype((X))>::type` than raw `decltype(X)`.

Comment: @blue: No need. The OP is explicitly writing: "*I'm using following code with C++11*"