# c++ - Mapping a class to a string

Tags: c++, string, class, dictionary

Is it at all possible to map a class and/or its subclasses, like myClass, to a string/int/whatever?

This is what I'm thinking of:

```
map<myClass, string> myMap = {
    {subclass1, "one"},
    {subclass2, "two"}
    //etc etc
}
```

I'm having trouble compiling working sample code. Could I get some help with that?

Note: I'm using c++ 11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`std::type_index`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index) for that:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <typeindex>

std::map<std::type_index, std::string> m { { typeid(myClass), "zero" }
                                         , { typeid(subclass1), "one" }
                                         , { typeid(subclass2), "two" }
                                         };
```

Comment: Awesome! This code works but how would I go about access the map? Attempting to pass the [] operator a class gives a ton of errors.

Comment: @Mastergeek you pass a `typeid`, of course. However, note that the types involved [**need** to have virtual methods](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1986448/85371) for this to work at _runtime_: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6dce760d9a52880c (see what happens if you remove the virtual destructor)

Comment: @Mastergeek: I think the page I linked to contains sufficient examples, non?

Comment: @sehe: `typeid` works on anything, but for references you only get *dynamic* lookup if the type is polymorphic.

Comment: @KerrekSB that's what I meant. "for _this_ to work" referred to what the OP was after. Also, I don't think "the type is polymorphic" has well-defined meaning (_static polymorphism_ anyone? In the words of ... someone else: "Types _aren't_ polymorphic. They're used _in polymorphic fashion_"). I prefer just saying "has a virtual member".

Comment: @sehe: I suppose I meant that the type [`std::is_polymorphic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_polymorphic) :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB Oh hey. I need to learn the traits of the trick. Or the tricks of the trait. Wait. There's something punny in there. :/ Thanks

Comment: @sehe: When talking type punning is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thanks all for the help. This is extremely useful for my project and I was very unsure how to do this.