# Use RTTI to get class name from object implementing interface c++

Tags: c++, reflection, unique-ptr

I have a class AnimalInterface in Animal namespace:

```
namespace Animal
{
    class AnimalInterface
    {
    public:
        AnimalInterface() = default;
        virtual ~AnimalInterface() = default;

        virtual std::string makeSound() = 0;
    };
}
```

Suppose I have 2 classes implementing from this interface

```
class Dog : public AnimalInterface
{
public:
    Dog() = default;
    ~Dog() = default;

    std::string makeSound()
    {
        return "Bark";
    }
};

class Cat : public AnimalInterface
{
public:
    Cat() = default;
    ~Cat() = default;

    std::string makeSound()
    {
        return "Meow";
    }
};
```

Now I have a class from where I call these functions. I would like to be able to get the class names of the animals from the objects using run time type information.

```
void AnimalSounds
{
    list<unique_ptr<AnimalInterface>> animals;
    animals.push_back(make_unique<Dog>());
    animals.push_back(make_unique<Cat>());

    for (const auto& animal : animals)
    {

        cout << typeid(animal).name() << " makes sound: " << animal->makeSound() << endl;
    }
}
```

I expect the output to be

```
Dog makes sound: Bark
Cat makes sound: Meow
```

Instead, I get the following

```
class std::unique_ptr<class Animal::AnimalInterface,struct std::default_delete<class Animal::AnimalInterface> > makes sound: Bark
class std::unique_ptr<class Animal::AnimalInterface,struct std::default_delete<class Animal::AnimalInterface> > makes sound: Meow
```

How do I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: *I would like to be able to get the class names of the animals from the objects using reflection.* -- There is no reflection in C++ at this time.  This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: The string returned by `typeid` is implementation defined. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986418/typeid-versus-typeof-in-c

Comment: Think about what type `animal` is. Is it really `Dog` or  `Cat`?  You can't rely on `typeid(...).name()` anyway, it's output is neither garantueed to be the class name, nor to be consistend (not even between executions of one and the same program).

Comment: How about -- `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<AnimalInterface>>` or if animals can have duplicate names `std::unordered_multimap<std::string, std::unique_ptr<AnimalInterface>>`?

Answer (score 4):

You need to dereference the pointer. That way you get the RTTI information from the object that it points to, not the pointer itself:

```cpp
const auto& animal_ref = *animal;
cout << typeid(animal_ref).name() << " makes sound: " << animal->makeSound() << endl;
```

```
3Dog makes sound: Bark
3Cat makes sound: Meow
```

Note that you will still have to deal with implementation-defined names as described in the comments. You can use your library's demangle function for that:

```cpp
int status;
const auto& animal_ref = *animal;
const auto name = abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(animal_ref).name(), 0, 0, &status);
cout << name << " makes sound: " << animal->makeSound() << endl;
```

```
Dog makes sound: Bark
Cat makes sound: Meow
```

Unless this question was asked for a better understanding of RTTI or for debugging purposes, I would still strongly advise you to reconsider your approach. This is nothing that your code should rely on.

(And yes, technically even demangling might not be enough, and the name *might* change between invocations. In the implementations that I have worked with, this never happened. At the point where we are talking about cats making meow, this is more a technicality than an actual issue.)

Answer (score 1):

I think the unexpected problem you have is that your `animals` list contains `unique_ptr` to `Animal`s. Therefore, when you iterate over that list, each `animal` in the loop is a `unique_ptr<Animal>`, which is a template with default arguments. To at least fix that problem, dereference the pointer before using `typeid`:

```
for (const auto& animal : animals)
{
  cout << typeid(*animal).name() << " makes sound: " << animal->makeSound() << endl;
}
```

However, what you get here is still implementation defined. Read up on RTTI for more information.

Answer (score 0):

1.) `animal` is a reference to some element from `animals`. What does `animals` contain? It contains `unique_ptr<AnimalInterface>`, so the compiler prints exactly the right thing, just a bit verbose.

2.) `typeif(...).name()` is not really refelction. In particular it doesn't give you any garantues about the result whatsoever. See also the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name):

> No guarantees are given; in particular, the returned string can be identical for several types and change between invocations of the same program.

3.) I can only think of one robust and standard compliant way to achieve what you want to: another virtual function that returns the animal kind. Or some compiler specific extension, but standard C++ doesn't offer any real reflection at the moment.