# Seeing what class an object is

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, pointers, radix

If I have a pointer to a base class `A` in C++, how would I be able to tell in my code that the pointer is to a derived class `B` or `C`?

Comment: Is this what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351845/finding-the-type-of-an-object-in-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the base class `A` is polymorphic (i.e. it has at least one virtual function), you can use `dynamic_cast`.  Given an `A* ap;`:

```
if (B* bp = dynamic_cast<B*>(ap)) {
    // the object is a B
}
else if (C* cp = dynamic_cast<C*>(ap)) {
    // the object is a C
}
```

Comment: In order to improve readability and avoid 'did you mean "=="' comments from the compiler, I prever `if((blah) != 0)`. Just a matter of taste.

Comment: @sje397:  That won't work because `blah` in this case is a declaration, not an expression.  Because it is a declaration, the `=` is not `operator=`, and I don't think most compilers would issue a warning here.

Comment: @James: still don't get it - it must evaluate to something 'false' to work as the condition in the `if` yes?

Comment: Also known as "Run Time Type Identification"

Comment: I'm with @sje397 here--what does the code mean? It seems like you're trying to assign something. Would the assignment return false if it failed?

Comment: @sje397 and @wrongusername:  if the object is not either the type being cast to or a type derived from the type being cast to, then `dynamic_cast` will return `0` which is evaluated as false.  Otherwise it returns a pointer to the object you already have a pointer to, but this pointer will know that it points to an object of the derived type.

Comment: I asked a question to help clarify: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427228/assignment-as-condition-adding-parentheses-causes-errors

Answer (score 2):

You generally shouldn't need to know:

```
struct A {
    virtual int generate_foo() = 0;
};

struct B : A {
    int generate_foo() { return 42; }
};

struct C : A {
    i_;
    C(int i) : i_(i) { }
    int generate_foo() { return i_++; }
};
```

If you have an `A*` you (1) know that it has a `generate_foo()` method, and (2) know that `generate_foo()` will generate an appropriate foo for whatever object you really do have.  In general that should be enough and you *should* be able to keep track of when you have an `A*`.

Philosophically, the designers of C++ spent years trying to avoid adding runtime type information because it' too easily used incorrectly.  However, they eventually decided that they were on the wrong end of a losing battle and added `dynamic_cast` and `typeinfo()`.  C++0x will add more.