# declaration as condition - adding parentheses causes errors

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, variable-assignment

Why is this ok:

```
if(int i = 1) {
}
```

...whereas the following produces errors?

```
if((int i = 1)) {
}
```

Under g++ (4.4.5) the latter gives:

> test.cpp:7: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
>   test.cpp:7: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘int’
>   test.cpp:9: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘else’
>   test.cpp:13: error: expected primary-expression before ‘}’ token
>   test.cpp:13: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token

Incidentally, the reason I'm asking is because of this answer: [Seeing what class an object is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426476/seeing-what-class-an-object-is/4426485#4426485)

I'm trying to find a way to make the condition more readable. Usually, I would prefer, for example:

```
if((x = y) != 0) {
```

to

```
if(x = y) {
```

...since it's more readable and silences compiler 'comments' suggesting I might have used the wrong operator. If I'm using a *declaration* as a condition, it doesn't produce the warning, but the readability still seems to suffer.

Comment: Why would you want to do either of these?

Comment: @Robin Welch - The use case and inspiration are here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426476/seeing-what-class-an-object-is/4426485#4426485

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because of the C++ standard, 6.4 p1.

> Selection statements choose one of several flows of control.

*selection-statement:*

```
if ( condition ) statement
if ( condition ) statement else statement
switch ( condition ) statement
```

*condition:*

```
expression
type-specifier-seq declarator = assignment-expression
```

Comment: I have added the start of the quote from the standard. The extra bit that is missing is that in the definition of `condition` it allows for extra parenthesis, but not definition of variables.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an assignment. It's a declaration. You can put declarations elsewhere as conditions, as in the following

```
if(int i = value) ...;
for(...; int i = value; ...) ...;
switch(int i = value) ...;
while(int i = value) ...;
```

This is a rarely used form, but it isn't an expression specified there. What you have done there is declaring a variable `i` which you can use in the body

```
// fire if get() returns non-null
if(weapon *w = get()) {
  w->fire();
}
```

And parentheses aren't allowed around such a declaration. I think that would make no sense.

Comment: And I should add, don't do this EVER.  Just because it's syntactically correct doesn't mean your fellow programmers will like you because of it.

Comment: @Neil - See the link in my comment under the question for a possible reason.

Comment: No doubt a reasons exists as demonstrated by your link.  Though there are clearer ways to do the same thing, so why sacrifice simplicity?

Comment: @Neil because it allows for user defined switch macros: http://bloglitb.blogspot.com/2010/11/fun-with-switch-statements.html

Comment: For another example, it can be used to inject variables into a block of code. Look the implementation of `BOOST_FOREACH` (if you dare :P, well, the idea is not that hard, metaprogramming to get the correct types is what makes the macro harder to read)

Comment: @Johannes - I edited the title somewhat to take into account your first two sentences.