# Why does typeid.name() return weird characters using GCC and how to make it print unmangled names?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, rtti

How come when I run this `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

struct Blah {};

int main() {
  cout << typeid(Blah).name() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

By compiling it with GCC version 4.4.4:

```
g++ main.cpp
```

I get this:

```
4Blah
```

On Visual C++ 2008, I would get:

```
struct Blah
```

Is there a way to make it just print `Blah` or `struct Blah`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print variable type in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81870/print-variable-type-in-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unmangling the result of std::type\_info::name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281818/unmangling-the-result-of-stdtype-infoname)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The return of `name` is implementation defined : an implementation is not even required to return different strings for different types.

What you get from g++ is a [decorated name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling), that you can "demangle" using the [`c++filt`](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.16/binutils/c_002b_002bfilt.html) command or [`__cxa_demangle`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html).

Comment: specifically `c++filt -t`

Comment: Ugh. Goddamn it GCC.

Answer (score 19):

The string returned is implementation defined.

What gcc is doing is returning the mangled name.
You can convert the mangled name into plain text with c++filt

```
> a.out | c++filt
```

Comment: And here's a example: assume the content of stdout is `PFPFiiEiiE`, we can use the shell command `echo "PFPFiiEiiE" | c++filt`, and the result would be `int (* (*)(int, int))(int)`.

Comment: You might (e.g on Ubuntu) also need to add `--types` to demangle type endcodings: `echo "PFPFiiEiiE" | c++filt --types`

Answer (score 13):

> Is there a way to make it just print
>
> `Blah` or `struct Blah`?

No. The result of `std::typeinfo::name()` is unspecified. It might even return the same string for all types (or, indeed, empty strings for all types) and the implementation would still be standard-conforming. You must not rely on its result. Really, the only thing I found it useful for was debugging.

Tell us what what you need it for. Often traits is what you use instead.

Comment: in my program, I just want to log my struct name to a logfile. Following the above example, I could have typed something like: `LOG("Blah");`. But I want to account for possibly changing the struct name in the future, so I'm trying to do: `LOG(typeinfo(Blah).name();`

Comment: @ShaChris23: Well, I guess then you'll just have to live with not all compilers doing it in the same way. Have a look, however, what the runtime lib emits if, instead of `blah`, you have a map of strings to vectors of lists of strings. That can very easily exceed any sensible limits for log file size.

Answer (score 8):

As others have said, the result here is *implementation-defined*, meaning that the implementation (i.e., the compiler toolchain) is free to define it how it wants, so long as it documents that somewhere.

From the C++ standard, section 18.5.1/1 [lib.type.info]:

> The class `type_info` describes type information generated by the implementation. Objects of this class
>   effectively store a pointer to a name for the type, and an encoded value suitable for comparing two types for
>   equality or collating order. The names, encoding rule, and collating sequence for types are all unspecified
>   and may differ between programs.

Answer (score 6):

in 4Blah, 4 is the number of letters in your class name. For example if your class name is myEmptyClass then it would print 12myEmptyClass.

Comment: you are right bro.

Answer (score 3):

`typeid().name()` is implementation dependent. It may even return empty string for every type. That would not be very useful implementation, but it would be valid.

Comment: No. It may not return empty string for every type. The way the string is represented is application defined but according to C++ standard it must differ a type from others. With empty strings you can't do it.

Comment: @RodrigoGurgel [No guarantees are given; in particular, the returned string can be identical for several types and change between invocations of the same program.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name)

Answer (score 1):

Use ./a.out | c++filt --types for GCC.

For more information follow the links below.

[https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/c_002b_002bfilt.html#:~:text=The%20c%2B%2Bfilt%201,that%20they%20can%20be%20read.&text=If%20the%20name%20decodes%20into,the%20original%20word%20is%20output.](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/c_002b_002bfilt.html#:%7E:text=The%20c%2B%2Bfilt%201,that%20they%20can%20be%20read.&text=If%20the%20name%20decodes%20into,the%20original%20word%20is%20output.)