# How to obtain scanned barcode type with zxing library?

Tags: iphone, zxing

How i can obtain bar code type with zxing library? Delegate method return only barcode in text.

Answer (score 0):

The delegate call back is,

```
- (void)decoder:(Decoder *)decoder didDecodeImage:(UIImage *)image usingSubset:(UIImage *)subset withResult:(TwoDDecoderResult *)twoDResult {
```

The readers property in Decoder.mm is a list of FormatReaders.

```
@interface FormatReader : NSObject {
      zxing::Reader *reader_;
}
```

The reader_ variable in FormatReader will be a C++ subclass of zxing::Reader, like QRCodeReader.  Checking this class name will help identify what symbology you're getting.  Beware some of them are 'MultiFormat' readers that combine other readers, so you might have to do some clever inspection.

See [How to get class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466088/how-to-get-class-name) for how to get class name in C++.

If you end up making helpful modifications, make sure to submit a patch back to zxing.  Good luck!