# how to get barcode type and format with zxing library

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, zxing

I use Zxing library for Barcode, QRCode and Data matrix scanning. scanning process is work fine.

I also get result string from didScanResult delegate method of ZXingWidgetController.

```
- (void)zxingController:(ZXingWidgetController*)controller didScanResult:(NSString *)result {
}
```

But I have one problem...

how to get **type** (Text, URL, Address book, Phone Number, Email address etc..) and **format** (QRCode, Data matrix or Barcode) **of result**.

please help...

and thanks in advance...

Comment: for format: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932367/how-to-obtain-scanned-barcode-type-with-zxing-library?rq=1

Comment: @peko this answer is not proper and also not working. I already see this and also this is not accepted....

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that currently you are using ZXingWidget right?
Since there is no way to get barcode format in this library. So what i have done is i replaced this library with ZXingObjC library to get barcode type as well as format.

```
-(void)captureResult:(ZXCapture *)capture result:(ZXResult *)result
{
    if (!result) return;
    // We got a result. Display information about the result onscreen.
    NSString *formatString = [self barcodeFormatToString:result.barcodeFormat]; 
    NSString *display = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Scanned!\n\nFormat: 
    %@\n\nContents:\n%@", formatString, result.text];
}
```