# Strange behaviour of the typeid operator?

Tags: c++, xcode, typeid

Using XCode 3.2.3 (64-bit), I get following strange output. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

struct student {

};

int main()  
{  
    int i;
    student obj;

    std::cout << typeid(i).name() << "\n";
    std::cout << typeid(obj).name() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
i  
7student
```

Comment: You say it is wrong - what do you expect to see?

Comment: type of the passing parameter to `typeid` as output. ie `int student` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81870/print-variable-type-in-c

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why typeid.name() returns weird characters using gcc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465872/why-typeid-name-returns-weird-characters-using-gcc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's going on is nothing special. Just that `typeid` doesn't promise to return the "original" name of the type, but just *a* name.

The function returns an *implementation-defined* string, which, if you're lucky, is recognizable, but it makes no promise of that.

Answer (score 8):

The `name()` member function of the `type_info` struct is implementation-specific.  There's no guarantee whatsoever that it will try to return something that matches what it says in the original program.  In fact, the C++ ISO standard (18.5.1.7) actually says that this function returns "an implementation-defined NTBS" (null-terminated byte string).  If it wanted to, it could have this always return the string "neener neerer I won't tell you the name of this type."  This contrasts with Java's `Class<?>` type, which has very strict restrictions on what it can and cannot return.

If you’d like to convert the name from `std::type_info` into something more human, readable, check [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281818/unmangling-the-result-of-stdtype-infoname) for details.