# In c++, vs2010 's typeid name differs to that of cocoa. Why? and Which one is right?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cocoa

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cout<<typeid(.01).name()<<endl;
    cout<<typeid(1).name()<<endl;
    cout<<typeid("ASDF").name()<<endl;
    //printing double, int, const char[5]

    /*
    CCLog("%s",typeid(.1).name());
    CCLog("%s",typeid(1).name());
    CCLog("%s",typeid("SDF").name());
    //but in cocoa: it is d, i, A4_c
    */

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Return types are in comments.

Comment: possible duplicate of [strange behaviour of typeid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642672/strange-behaviour-of-typeid)

Comment: Check your compile docs for a way to demangle the names, for example gcc uses [cxxabi.h](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html) for that purpose.

Comment: Downvoted for the `_tmain` and still asking for platform independence.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The contents of the string returned by `type_info::name` are implementation defined. It can (and likely will) be different for different compilers. So they are both right.

Comment: if the names cannot be used as a identifier, what are they for?

Comment: @AbbyChauYuHoi: They're for implementation-dependent uses. If your implementation says that the name for a type will uniquely identify that type, then you can use it as a unique identifier for that type.