# what does the the St26 mean in c++ iterator::iterator_category

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, typeinfo

I wrote a code to test some iterator_category of C++ container's iterator's type.

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <iterator>     // std::iterator_traits
#include <typeinfo>     // typeid
#include <list>
#include <deque>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

 list<int>::iterator::iterator_category itr;
 std::cout << typeid(itr).name() << endl;
 std::cout << typeid(vector<int>::iterator::iterator_category).name() << endl;
 std::cout << typeid(deque<int>::iterator::iterator_category).name() << endl;
 std::cout << typeid(itr).name() << endl;

 return 0;
}
```

I run this code in editplus.
But the result is weird.
[image: **enter image description here**]

What does the **"St26"** before the type mean?

Comment: I suspect it's a version number of the STL library.

Comment: I don't know what it means, but the code it doesn't compile on my Mac, nor on ideone.com, (and not just because this is missing `using namespace std;`), so I suspect it is implementation specific to your platform.

Comment: After I fix the issues so it compiles, Visual Studio 2013 says `struct std::bidirectional_iterator_tag` or `struct std::random_access_iterator_tag` so perhaps in your implementation `St` means `struct`.  It's implementation specific.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to paste the "using namespace std";

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465872/why-typeid-name-returns-weird-characters-using-gcc Using `a.exe | c++-filt -t` produces a more human-readable result.