# How to endlessly loop over map

Tags: c++

I need to iterate over the entire map without stopping the loop.
My example works but it uses two loops, can this be fixed?

I think it's possible to do this using only one for loop

```
#include <map>

map<int, int>map2;

    map2[1] = 11;
    map2[2] = 12;
    map2[3] = 13;

    for (;;)
    {
        for (auto& a : map2)
        {

            cout << a.first << " : " << a.second << '\n';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why you need two loops ? Why u r using infinite for loop before map iteration ?

Comment: There is no array in your code.

Comment: I am looping through the map I need this for my program.

Comment: i think your code is already the best way to do it. 2 loops.
if your list is a normal array(not a map but list that can be indexed by int) you just to need to increment the index with wrap-around like this: `index = (index+1)%yourList.size();`

Comment: an array is what I mean map; my translation is bad.

Comment: looping nonstop will eat cpu for other threads. atleast add some `sleep()`.

Comment: Do you mean `for (auto it = map.begin(); ; ++it) { if (it == map.end()) { it = map.begin(); } cout << it->first << " : " << it->second << '\n'; }`?

Comment: So in one loop I can’t do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `std::map::iterator`. That way you can just check if the iterator is at the end and if so reset it to the beginning.

```
map<int, int>::iterator it;
for ( it = map2.begin(); it != map2.end(); it == std::prev( map2.end() ) ? it = map2.begin() : it++ )
{
    cout << it->first << " : " << it->second << '\n';
}
```

**Clarification**

```
it == std::prev( map2.end() ) ? it = map2.begin() : it++
```

That is the ternary operator. You first ask if the iterator is equal to the last element in the map. We add the `std::prev()` in order to get the last element as `map::end()` provides us with a [past-the-end](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/end/) value.

```
it == std::prev(map2.end())
```

If it is the last element you set the iterator to the beginning of the map.

```
it = map2.begin()
```

Else the iterator is incremented and you get the next element

```
it++
```

See also: [Loop through map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26281979/c-loop-through-map)

Comment: and this loop can capture map changes like mine?

Comment: Yes it detects whenever a new value is pushed into the map. The iterator method is more or less the same as `for(auto& a : map2)` with the addition of the iterator reset

Comment: For further reading on the difference between iterator and range based for: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29578219/range-based-for-loop-vs-regular-iterator-for-loop)

Comment: Is it possible to shorten the cycle a little?
he looks long, poorly readable.

Comment: Your original solution using two loops was more succinct and readable, that's why. Typically, you can either have readable, or "in one loop".

Comment: And what does
mean? `prev(end(map2))`

Comment: Edited my answer for clarification

Comment: nothing if i delete? `it != map2.end(); `Or the loop may crash sometime because of this.

Comment: You could delete it but it would definetly hurt the readability even further. You could even do 

    `#define mBegin it = map2.begin()`
    `#define mLoop it == std::prev( map2.end() ) ? it = map2.begin() : it++`
and then
    `for ( mBegin;; mLoop )`

Comment: Not thanks, `#define` is a bad idea, it is better not to use it, only very in extreme cases.
Because of it, people commit very strong bugs in programs.