# Proper way to identify type of derived class(type entity VS dynamic_case)

Tags: c++, inheritance, dynamic-cast, typechecking

I'm trying to implement data classes derived from one base class.

And each derived classes has **different data fields**.

So the each instances have to be handled differently depending on type of data instance.

I made one example code for this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
using namespace std;

enum DataTypes{
    EMPTY = 0,
    TYPE1,
    TYPE2
};
class DataBase {
public:
    DataBase():type(EMPTY){}
    virtual ~DataBase(){}
    DataTypes getType() const{return type;}

protected:
    DataBase(DataTypes n):type(n){}
    DataTypes type;
};

class DataType1 :public DataBase {
public:
    DataType1(): DataBase(TYPE1){}

    string data_for_class1;
};

class DataType2 :public DataBase {
public:
    DataType2(): DataBase(TYPE2){}

    string data_for_class2;
};

boost::shared_ptr<DataBase> createInstance(int n){
    boost::shared_ptr<DataBase> p;
    if(n == 1){
        p.reset(new DataType1);
        boost::shared_ptr<DataType1> temp = boost::static_pointer_cast<DataType1>(p);
        temp->data_for_class1 = "[Data for DataType1]";
    }
    else if(n==2){
        p.reset(new DataType2);
        boost::shared_ptr<DataType2> temp = boost::static_pointer_cast<DataType2>(p);
        temp->data_for_class2 = "[Data for DataType2]";
    }

    return p;
}

int main() {
    boost::shared_ptr<DataBase> p = createInstance(2);
    try{
        /*
        if p is an instance of DataType1
            process p as DataType1;
        else if p is an instance of DataType2
            process p as DataType2;
        else
            throw exception("Empty data");
        */
    }catch(runtime_error& e){
        cerr<<e.what()<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The commented part in try-catch expression should be filled.

After thinking hard,I got two possible solutions.

### 1. checking  `type` field in `DataBase` class

For doing this,

- `DataBase` class should have `type` field.
- Every classes derived from `DataBase` are responsible for calling constructor(`DataBase(DataTypes n)`) with appropriate parameter.

Code :

```
switch (p->getType()){
    case TYPE1:
    {
        cout<<"This is an instance of DataType1"<<endl;
        boost::shared_ptr<DataType1> temp = boost::static_pointer_cast<DataType1>(p);
        cout<<temp->data_for_class1<<endl;
    }
        break;
    case TYPE2:
    {
        cout<<"This is an instance of DataType2"<<endl;
        boost::shared_ptr<DataType2> temp = boost::static_pointer_cast<DataType2>(p);
        cout<<temp->data_for_class2<<endl;
    }
        break;
    case EMPTY: default:
        throw runtime_error("Data is empty");
}
```

### 2. using `dynamic_cast` for all derived classes

In contrast to case1, this method

- does not require `DataBase` to have additional field for type-checking.
- But I don't know `dynamic_cast` is good way of doing this.

Code :

```
if(boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<DataType1>(p)){
    cout<<"This is an instance of DataType1"<<endl;
    boost::shared_ptr<DataType1> temp = boost::static_pointer_cast<DataType1>(p);
    cout<<temp->data_for_class1<<endl;
}
else if(boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<DataType2>(p)){
    cout<<"This is an instance of DataType2"<<endl;
    boost::shared_ptr<DataType2> temp = boost::static_pointer_cast<DataType2>(p);
    cout<<temp->data_for_class2<<endl;
}
else{
    throw runtime_error("Data is empty");
}
```

Both of the above ways, I could get working codes. But I'm not sure this is proper way of doing this.

If the above codes have potential problems or if you know a better solution, please share your nice idea.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also solution #3 with a virtual `getType` (and no `type` field stored in the base).

```
class DataBase {
public:
    DataBase() {}
    virtual ~DataBase() {}

    virtual DataTypes getType() { return EMPTY; } // or '= 0;'
};

class DataType1 :public DataBase {
public:
    //...
    DataTypes getType() { return TYPE1; };
};

class DataType2 :public DataBase {
public:
    //...
    DataTypes getType() { return TYPE2; };
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems better solution than #1.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using polymorphishm, then it's better to take advantage of language features provided to support. Hence #2 is better than #1

you may also want to avoid dynamic_cast and use run-time type check provided by language - "typeid(*p).name". That would give you the object represented by "p".

re-writing your example using this approach:

```
if(typeid(*p).name == "DataType1"){
    cout<<"This is an instance of DataType1"<<endl;
    boost::shared_ptr<DataType1> temp = boost::static_pointer_cast<DataType1>(p);
    cout<<temp->data_for_class1<<endl;
}
else if(typeid(*p).name == "DataType2"){
    cout<<"This is an instance of DataType2"<<endl;
    boost::shared_ptr<DataType2> temp = boost::static_pointer_cast<DataType2>(p);
    cout<<temp->data_for_class2<<endl;
}
else{
    throw runtime_error("Data is empty");
}
```

Comment: Wow, it's good. But in my PC, `name()` call returns instance name with **9** ahead(ie, `9DataType1`). Do you know what is this?

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465872/why-does-typeid-name-return-weird-characters-using-gcc-and-how-to-make-it-prin

Comment: ok. the result of `name()` call seems to be different with library implementations. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/typeinfo/type_info/name/.

Comment: in your case, the .name() seems to return mangled class name.

Answer (score 0):

Way 1 is more efficient because it don't uses run-time-type-information.

Answer (score 0):

All of the options given are not great designs, because they appear to process a DataBase, but really only work with the subtypes of DataBase that are also in some special list of supported types.  The casts give it away.  More formally, this violates the Liskov Substitution Principle.

since the class is called "DataBase", I'm guessing that you don't want to just put a pure virtual process(...) method in DataBase that the subclasses would implement.

In that case, you should use double dispatch: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch

For example, you can make an interface DBConsumer like this:

```
class DBConsumer
{
    public:
    virtual void accept(DataType1 &data) = 0;
    virtual void accept(DataType2 &data) = 0;
}
```

Then, in your base class:

```
class DataBase
{
    ...
    virtual void sendTo(DBConsumer &consumer) = 0;
    ...
}
```

And implement that in each subclass, to call the appropriate overload:

```
class DataType1
{
    ...
    void sendTo(DBConsumer &consumer)
    {
        consumer.accept(*this); //calls DataType1 overload
    }
    ...
}
class DataType2
{
    ...
    void sendTo(DBConsumer &consumer)
    {
        consumer.accept(*this); //calls DataType2 overload
    }
    ...
}
```

Now, if you want to process DataTypes, you implement a consumer that implements the accept() overloads for each subclass:

```
int main()
{
    ...
    MyDBConsumer myConsumer;
    boost::shared_ptr<DataBase> p = createInstance(2);
    p->sendTo(myConsumer);
}
```

Tada! no casting and no magic lists of supported types.  And when someone adds a new DataType3 subclass, the *compiler will ensure that it's supported by all DBConsumers*.