# How does "C++filt" find the actual typenames?

Tags: c++

Sorry if this is silly but I am puzzled by this.

I did [Google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=how+c%2B%2Bfilt+work%3F&oq=how+c%2B%2B&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i64j69i60l3.3149j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) my question but was not able to find any relevant results.

For the below code compiled and written to a.out :

```
char x;
cout<<typeid(x).name()<<endl;
```

`/a.out` gave me `c` where I expected `char`. I found this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465872/why-does-typeid-name-return-weird-characters-using-gcc-and-how-to-make-it-prin) question and concluded that we need to demangle the result using `c++filt -t` and so I did this :

```
./a.out | c++filt -t
```

and hurray ! I got the demangled (This is not a dictionary word) name `char`.

Fair enough !

But the question that perplexes me is how did `c++filt` find that?

I doubled check what a pipe does [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-4.html). If I understand correctly it just passes the output, in this case, `c` to the `c++filt -t`.

Where did `c++filt` look for the information?

How the process of demangling work with `c++filt`?

Comment: Tell me, in your own words, what does `c++filt` do?

Comment: "I did Google this but not able to find any relevant results." Please define "this"

Comment: The character "c" has magic properties. As it turns out, your SO name unfortunately does not.

Comment: @CommuSoft. It is actually pretty clear what the problem is if you read all the way to the end. Unfortunately it is an issue of knowing where to look for documentation, not a specific programming problem.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart : If I am not mistaken, it demangles C++ and Java symbols. I did look at the man-page before posting this. Removed the last part of the question. thought that would be funny :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is written in the man :

```
c++filt copies each file name in sequence,  and writes it on
the standard output after decoding  symbols that look like
C++ mangled names.

c++filt handles Solaris Studio C++  legacy versions as well
as  the current version.

c++filt reads from  the standard input if no input file is
specified.
```

And here is a little introduction about demangling :

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html

```
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <cxxabi.h>

struct empty { };

template <typename T, int N>
  struct bar { };


int main()
{
  int     status;
  char   *realname;

  // exception classes not in <stdexcept>, thrown by the implementation
  // instead of the user
  std::bad_exception  e;
  realname = abi::__cxa_demangle(e.what(), 0, 0, &status);
  std::cout << e.what() << "\t=> " << realname << "\t: " << status << '\n';
  free(realname);


  // typeid
  bar<empty,17>          u;
  const std::type_info  &ti = typeid(u);

  realname = abi::__cxa_demangle(ti.name(), 0, 0, &status);
  std::cout << ti.name() << "\t=> " << realname << "\t: " << status << '\n';
  free(realname);

  return 0;
}
```

This prints

```
  St13bad_exception       => std::bad_exception   : 0
  3barI5emptyLi17EE       => bar<empty, 17>       : 0
```

Comment: Cheers pal !! `c++filt copies each file name in sequence..` is what  I am looking for . I running a cygwin and its man page for ``c++filt` didn't include this info..

Answer (score 4):

> Where did c++filt look for the information?
>
> How the process of demangling work with c++filt?

The way mangling works depends on what your platform is. And therefore the way the demangling works also depends on it.

The programmers of `c++filt` looked at the specification that describes how symbols are mangled on your platform. Or, possibly, they simply call a function that's provided by the implementation, which demangles the symbols.

In the latter case, the people who implemented the compiler and therefore the demangling function, know how the symbols are mangled because they implemented the mangling in the first place.

c++filt is open source software, you can read their source to find out what it does.

---

If you're interested in how to demangle symbols yourself, I recommend taking a look at the manual of your compiler.

Comment: Thanks for the info on mangling  & demangling. I will have a closer look at the c++-filt documentation.