# How can I get the data type for boost::any variable?

Tags: c++, boost, types

I am looking for a way to check boost::any data type.
If i assign an int to boost::any like:

```
boost::any num1 = 5;
```

And then use typeid(num1).name() , i want my output to be "int" so that i can use it in a if else statement in the future. However for some reason it keeps giving me this as the data type: `N5boost3anyE`

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/any.hpp>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int     a;
    double  b;
    float   c;
    bool    d;
    int16_t e;
    int32_t f;


    cout << "     int: " << typeid(a).name() << endl;
    cout << "sizeof(): " << sizeof(a) << endl << endl;

    cout << "  double: " << typeid(b).name() << endl;
    cout << "sizeof(): " << sizeof(b) << endl << endl;

    cout << "   float: " << typeid(c).name() << endl;
    cout << "sizeof(): " << sizeof(c) << endl << endl;

    cout << "    bool: " << typeid(d).name() << endl;
    cout << "sizeof(): " << sizeof(d) << endl << endl;

    cout << " int16_t: " << typeid(e).name() << endl;
    cout << "sizeof(): " << sizeof(e) << endl << endl;

    cout << " int32_t: " << typeid(f).name() << endl;
    cout << "sizeof(): " << sizeof(f) << endl << endl;

    boost::any num1 = 5;
    cout << "typeid(num1).name(): " << typeid(num1).name() << endl;

    boost::any num2 = "dog";
    cout << "typeid(num2).name(): " << typeid(num2).name() << endl;

}
```

Output:

```
johns-Air:cpp jdoe$ ./main 
int: i
sizeof(): 4

double: d
sizeof(): 8

float: f
sizeof(): 4

    bool: b
sizeof(): 1

int16_t: s
sizeof(): 2

int32_t: i
sizeof(): 4

typeid(num1).name(): N5boost3anyE
typeid(num2).name(): N5boost3anyE
```

Comment: You don't need this for an if-else. It's expected to use `any_cast` to (try to) cast back to the actual type. Given that you're trying more than one, there's a chance that `boost::variant` is more suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `boost::any`'s member function `type()` which returns a `const std::type_info&` of the contained value

```
cout << "num1.type().name(): " << num1.type().name() << endl;
```

Comment: method boost::any::type::name don't return name clearly which is mangled.To demangle refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465872/why-does-typeid-name-return-weird-characters-using-gcc-and-how-to-make-it-prin