# How to understand c++ alias template?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<typeinfo>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
using constptr1 = const T*;

template<typename T>
using constptr2 = const constptr1<T *>;

int main() 
{
    constptr2<char> c = nullptr;
    cout << typeid(decltype(c)).name() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I'm learning C++ type alias, and see this weird code.
Two questions:

1. This code output `PKPc`, what it means?
2. Why the `constptr2<char>` is equal to `char * const* const`?

Comment: The output of `type_info::name` is implementation-defined. It will have different meaning on different compilers. You can't rely on it to uniquely identify types. To identify a type it is easier to use some undefined template, e.g. `template<typename T> struct Undefined;` and then define a variable of that type with the template argument being the type that you want to identify, e.g. `Undefined<decltype(c)> _;`. Then the compiler will complain with an error message that `Undefined` is undefined and include the name of the `decltype(c)` type in the error message.

Comment: "_Why the constptr2<char> is equal to char * const* const?_": Why not? What do you think it should be or what step in deducing the type is unclear to you?

Comment: Related/dupe: [Why does typeid.name() return weird characters using GCC and how to make it print unmangled names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465872/why-does-typeid-name-return-weird-characters-using-gcc-and-how-to-make-it-prin)

Comment: You need to understand the object declaration syntax 1st. Then use **east-const** notation and manually interpret your aliases to see what they do.

Comment: I want to know how to deduce this type `char * const* const` @user17732522