# C++: Identify type of an object

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding the type of an object in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351845/finding-the-type-of-an-object-in-c)

... Without using some kind of magic value ID? Are there any language features or maybe some techniques that allow me to do that?

Comment: That depends on what you're trying to do. If you want to tell if your object is of a certain type, then @miku's link is good. If you want to get the type name of an arbitrary object, there's `typeid` (include `<typeinfo>` first).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do that ??
In any case, just given a void * it is not possible to find out what type the object is atleast in C++. The QueryInterface pattern came into existense for this and other reasons in the COM model.

Answer (score 0):

There's always `typeid`.  But what exactly are you trying to do?  The
results of `typeid( object ).name()` are implementation specified, and
whether they're useful for what you're trying to do or not depends on
what you are trying to do, and which implementation you're using.  (You
can use a wrapper around `typeid( object )` as a key into a map.)