# How do I do C# typeof(bool) in C++/CLI?

Tags: c#, types, c++-cli

I'm trying to find out if VisualHint.SmartPropertyGrid.PropertyGrid will meet my needs for setting properties, and some of my properties are boolean values.

One of the parameters is

```
//   container:
//     The instance of an object containing the C# property displayed in this new
//     property.
```

So in general, I can just hand it a suitable object - but, booleans are value types, not objects.

In C#, the right syntax is to enter the container as `typeof(bool)`.  Is there any sensible way to do this in C++, or do I have to make my own bool object?

Comment: There is a [Previous answer][1] on the site


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351845/finding-the-type-of-an-object-in-c

Comment: In C++ the built in types do not have an alternate object representation. If you need one, but the `bool` in a `struct`.

Comment: For the benefit of anyone else using a SmartPropertyGrid, I was asking the wrong question.  The container can be `this`, where `this` has a `public: property bool boolprop` and then the membername is set to `"boolprop"`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The exact equivalent of C#'s typeof operator is provided in C++/CLI by the `typeid` operator:

```
Type^ t = bool::typeid;
```