# Checking if a pointer points to a particular class C++

Tags: c++, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding the type of an object in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351845/finding-the-type-of-an-object-in-c)

I have a question with checking pointers to see if they conform to a particular derived class and take necessary action.

Lets say I currently have 2 derived classes `DerivedClass1` and `DerivedClass2` and the base class `BaseClass`. I would like to check the following action.

`Ptr<BaseClass> ptr;`

`if (ptr points to DerivedClass1)`
`{`
action1
`}`
else
`{`
action2
`}`

How do I check for ptr points to a particular DerivedClass?

Comment: No, most probably you *don't* want to know what the dynamic type of `*ptr` is.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If `BaseClass` is polymorphic (contains virtual functions), you can test:

```
if (dynamic_cast<DerivedClass1*>(ptr.get()))
```

But usually you should use dynamic dispatch as unwind suggests, possibly a Visitor pattern, for this sort of thing.  Littering your code with `dynamic_cast` makes it hard to maintain.  I use `dynamic_cast` almost NEVER.

Comment: I agree that we mostly should avoid this, but I needed it for a test method to confirm that an object was of a certain type. So there are use cases. Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

If you were to think a bit more object-orientedly, you would just make it a virtual method on the base class:

```
Ptr<BaseClass> ptr;

ptr->Action();
```

and have each class implement it as needed. I realize this isn't an actual answer, but it's an alternative way of accomplishing your goal which is often considered to be better, which is why I think it's worth mentioning.

Comment: thanks. this was my initial thought but I had the problem of having a const method in a particular class and a non const in another one, thus was trying to add this behavior in a new method.

Answer (score 9):

```
if(dynamic_cast<DerivedClass1*>(ptr))
{
  // Points to DerivedClass1
}
else if(dynamic_cast<DerivedClass2*>(ptr)
{
  // Points to DerivedClass2
}
```

Comment: If there was a third level, say, `DerivedClass1_1` and `DerivedClass1_2`, the first `if` clause would treat them both as a `DerivedClass1` - That might or might not be what the OP wants.

Comment: @Component10 I've simply answered the OP's question. I don't condone this practice, and usually find this is only needed when _bad design decisions_ have been made. Thanks for pointing the inheritance situation out though, in case the OP decides to try something like this.