# How can I check an object's class in C++?

Tags: c++, class, testing

Suppose I have a vector of objects of a base class, but use it to contain a number of derived classes. I want to check whether or not a member of that vector is of a specific class. How do I do that? I can think of making a template of a derived class that takes in a parameter of the base class, but I am not sure how I can compare the class with the object.

Comment: Here is a possible place to start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351845/finding-the-type-of-an-object-in-c

Comment: If you have a vector of objects of a base class you don't have any objects of derived types; they got sliced when they were stored in the vector.

Comment: The real question is why do you need to know the type at all. More often than not it is a design flaw.

Comment: You're misunderstanding what you're doing. A vector is a homogeneous array of elements of the same type. Either you've sliced your objects into base objects, or you have a vector of pointers. In any event, your design is probably misguided.

Comment: @PeteBecker good point. I totally missed that 'detail'

Comment: Usually when I need to store elements of different types in a vector I actually store pointers to an element of the base class in it. I assumed this was the case.

Comment: My base class vector has only derived classes. There are multiple types of derived classes, but I want to know a way in order to determine whether or not an element of that vector is of a particular type.

Answer (score 2):

If your base class has some virtual members (i.e. it's polymorphic, as I think it should be in a case like this one) you could try to [down cast](http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=19642) each member to find out its type (i.e. using `dynamic_cast`).

Otherwise you could use [RTTI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) (i.e. [`typeid`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/typeinfo/type_info/)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [dynamic_cast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_cast)

But if you need to do that, then you probably have a design problem. you should use polymorphism or templates to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

check out this example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <typeinfo>

class A
{
public:
    virtual ~A()
    {
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual ~B()
    {
    }
};

void main()
{
    A *a = new A();
    B *b = new B();

    if (typeid(a) == typeid(b))
    {
        cout << "a type equals to b type\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "a type is not equals to b type\n";
    }

    if (dynamic_cast<A *>(b) != NULL)
    {
        cout << "b is instance of A\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "b is not instance of A\n";
    }

    if (dynamic_cast<B *>(a) != NULL)
    {
        cout << "a is instance of B\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "a is not instance of B\n";
    }

    a = new B();

    if (typeid(a) == typeid(b))
    {
        cout << "a type equals to b type\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "a type is not equals to b type\n";
    }

    if (dynamic_cast<B *>(a) != NULL)
    {
        cout << "a is instance of B\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "a is not instance of B\n";
    }
}
```