# How to find out what type of object a pointer points to in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism, instance

Let's say I have `class SuperClass { public: int a; }` and `class SubClass : SuperClass { public: int b; }` and I took a pointer to an instance of the SubClass `SubClass *subPointer` and addressed that pointer to a SuperClass pointer `SuperClass *superPointer = subPointer`. Now of course I can always cast the `superPointer` object to a pointer of SubClass because the only thing it stores is an adress. But how would I know if the object `superPointer` is pointing to an instance of SubClass or is just a SuperClass pointer?

Comment: This can't be done in general, though RTTI will tell you in most cases if you compile with it.

Comment: In addition to @Antimony's suggestions there are ways to build this knowledge into the objects themselves, but they generally require that everything inherits from some god class (yet another `TObject`, anyone?). Most people will try to dissuade you from doing this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding the type of an object in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351845/finding-the-type-of-an-object-in-c)

Comment: As the proposed duplicate indicates, the easiest thing to do is to add a virtual destructor to `SuperClass`, and then test the result of `dynamic_cast<SubClass *>(superPointer)`.

Comment: See it in action here: http://ideone.com/hUiIfE

Answer (score 12):

You usually *don't* want to use `typeid` for this.

You usually want to use `dynamic_cast` instead:

```
if (SubClass *p = dynamic_cast<SubClass *>(SuperClassPtr))
    // If we get here (the `if` succeeds) it was pointing to an object of 
    // the derived class and `p` is now pointing at that derived object.
```

A couple of notes though. First of all, you need at least one virtual function in the base class for this to work (but if it doesn't have a virtual function, why are you inheriting from it?)

Second, wanting this very often tends to indicate design problems with the code. In most cases, you want to define a virtual function in the base class, which you (if necessary) override in the derived class to do whatever's needed so you can just use a pointer to the base class throughout.

Finally, as it stands right now, most of the conversions will fail -- you've used the default (private) inheritance, which prevents the implicit conversion from `derived *` to `base *` that you'd normally expect to see happen (you probably want `class SubClass : public SuperClass`).

Comment: Easy to have at least one virtual function - just make a virtual destructor.  You need that anyway.

Comment: @paddy, Too bad there's no easy way to do `virtual ~Class() = 0 = default;`

Comment: +1 For pointing out that the need for `dynamic_cast` usually indicates a design-flaw.

Answer (score 4):

Use RTTI machanism. Like:

```
if(typeid(*superPointer) == typeid(SuperClass)) superPointer->dosomething();
if(typeid(*superPointer) == typeid(SubClass)) superPointer->dosomethingelse();
```

Comment: Have you tested this? I have come across issues where this returns the superPointer's information every time.