# Compare 2 derived objects of base class

Tags: c++, class, compare, derived-class, base-class

I have something like this:

```
class A
{
public:
    A();
    ~A();
};

class B : public A
{
 //stuff
};

class C : public A
{
 //stuff
};

class D : public A
{
 //stuff
};

void Collision()
{
 //obj is a multidimensional array of class A that stores objects from class B, C and D
 if(obj[x][y] != B && obj[x][y] != C) //type name is not allowed
    doStuff();
}
```

I'm getting the error: *type name is not allowed*

I know it is not suposed to compare the objects like this, but i dont know how i should do it.

Comment: If `obj` is an array of polymorphic objects rather than pointers to polymorphic objects you're already in for a world of hurt.

Comment: obj is defined like this: A ***obj

Comment: This may be what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351845/finding-the-type-of-an-object-in-c

Comment: Then you're sort of ok. I recommend using `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>>>>`. Replace `std::vector` with `std::array` if the size of your arrays are fixed. Replace `std::unique_ptr` with `std::shared_ptr` or `std::weak_ptr` as appropriate.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what exactly do you mean with _'compare'_? Do you want to know if an object is of a specific type, or do you want to compare two objects of different kind?

Comment: I want to know if the object obj is a object of type B or C, in this particular case i want to know if they're different from B anc C, meaning i just want objects from type D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <typeinfo>

void Collision()
{
    if (typeid(obj[x][y]) != typeid(B) && typeid(obj[x][y]) != typeid(C)) 
        doStuff();
}
```