# dynamic_cast not throwing exceptions as expected

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

Based on this answer...

> [Finding the type of an object in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351845/finding-the-type-of-an-object-in-c)

...I wrote this code:

```
        static TVALUE getUpperBound()
        {
            SomeStruct<TVALUE>* t;

            try
            {
                dynamic_cast<SomeStruct<bool>*> (t);
                return 1;
            }
            catch (int e)
            {
            }

            try
            {
                dynamic_cast<SomeStruct<unsigned char>*> (t);
                return 255;
            }
            catch (int e)
            {
            }

            try
            {
                dynamic_cast<SomeStruct<unsigned int>*> (t);
                return 65535;
            }
            catch (int e)
            {
            }

            return 0;
        }
```

But it doesn't work :-/

I know there are OTHER ways to do this (using includes) but I need to get this technique working.

*I can't include any includes in my code (it's a long story, but I simply can't)... hence this attempt at doing something that could be done easily with climits or typeinfo.*

Can anyone please explain to me why this doesn't work?

Edit 1:

Thanks guys. I missed the reference vs pointer bit.

This works now:

```
template <typename TVALUE>
TVALUE getUpperBound()
{
    SomeStruct<TVALUE>* t;

    if (dynamic_cast<SomeStruct<bool>*> (t) != nullptr)
        return 1;
    if (dynamic_cast<SomeStruct<unsigned char>*> (t) != nullptr)
        return 255;
    if (dynamic_cast<SomeStruct<unsigned int>*> (t) != nullptr)
        return 65535;

    return 0;
}
```

Edit 2:

I tried @StilesCrisis advice and used template specialization

```
template <typename TVALUE>
TVALUE getUpperBound();

template <>
bool getUpperBound<bool>()
{
    return 1;
}

template <>
unsigned char getUpperBound<unsigned char>()
{
    return 255;
}

template <>
unsigned int getUpperBound<unsigned int>()
{
    return 65535;
}
```

Works a charm. Much better implementation. Thanks!

Comment: This will throw an exeption when you will use cast to reference type, but you are using pointers. Read documentation carefully

Comment: @user2451677: Why do you write answers as comments?

Comment: I have no time to write more detailed answer

Comment: Your sample code would be better as a template specialization. Much less expensive and equally expressive.

Comment: Can you please explain?

Comment: Now it's time to learn about `numeric_limits`. :)

Comment: :) I can't use header files (really) ...otherwise I would. If you write as an answer I will be happy to mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are casting to a pointer. `bad_cast` is only generated when casting to a reference.

You can just check for `nullptr` if casting to a reference isn't desirable.

Answer (score 4):

`dynamic_cast` only throws exceptions on failure if its template argument is a reference type.
When it's a pointer type, `dynamic_cast` instead evaluates to `NULL` on failure.

This is made very clear in [the preferred language reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast), for which you could simply have Googled:

> 5c) Otherwise, the runtime check fails. If the `dynamic_cast` is used on pointers, the null pointer value of type _new_type_ is returned. If it was used on references, the exception `std::bad_cast` is thrown.

I also don't understand why you expect an `int` to be thrown, rather than something that derives `std::exception`. Perhaps you were hoping that `return` in a `try` block jumps to the matching `catch` block? It doesn't.

Comment: dynamic_cast is not a template. It looks like template

Comment: It is a template. Sorry for not making that clearer.