# Is checking of object type really always sign of bad design?

Tags: c++, types

I have a source of some lines of text, each of which is a message, representing object of some type. I'm making a parser for these lines, which should take the text line as input and give the ready to use object as output. So I make the following hierarchy of classes:

```
class Message
{
public:
    virtual ~Message(){};
};

class ObjectTypeA : public Message
{/*...*/};
class ObjectTypeB : public Message
{/*...*/};
class ObjectTypeC : public Message
{/*...*/};
```

and here's how it's used:

```
std::shared_ptr<Message> parseLine(std::string& line);

void doWork()
{
    std::string line;
    while(getLine(line))
    {
        std::shared_ptr<Message> object=parseLine(line);
        if(dynamic_cast<ObjectTypeA*>(object.get()))
            doSomethingA(*static_cast<ObjectTypeA*>(object.get()));
        else if(dynamic_cast<ObjectTypeB*>(object.get()))
            doCompletelyUnrelatedProcessing(*static_cast<ObjectTypeB*>(object.get()));
        else if(dynamic_cast<ObjectTypeC*>(object.get()))
            doSomethingEvenMoreDifferent(*static_cast<ObjectTypeC*>(object.get()));
    }
}
```

Here the parser would be a library function, and the objects don't know in advance how they will be processed. So, I can't put the processing code to a virtual function of `Message` implementations.

But many of the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351845) say that if one needs to check type of the object, it's a sign of bad design. But I can't seem to see what's bad here. Is there any better way to organize the solution?

Comment: why not have a virtual method in the base class which is then imlpemented correctly for each *type*?

Comment: I'd also opt for a pure abstract interface.

Comment: It's not *always* bad design - sweeping generalisations are always wrong. But this example could easily be simplified to use a virtual function rather than a type check. (Perhaps in conjunction with the Visitor pattern or similar, if you want to decouple the doing of the things from the message types.)

Comment: This is even wrong: `dynamic_cast<ObjectTypeA*>(&object)`

Comment: by the way, although I've posted an answer, I've recommended a close based on the fact that this is really an opinion-based question (though an interesting one). May democracy decide whether it was wise to post an answer or not!

Comment: Type-switching is often a sign that the code as a whole could be reorganised, it's not "bad design" (whatever that is) in itself. Except for using virtual functions, there's probably no better way to organise this *particular* solution. But your solution (i.e. creating a generic object which isn't really "ready to use" and then type-switching in order to use it) may not be a "good" design in itself.  Without knowing the particulars of the actual program, it's impossible to suggest how, or if, it could be refactored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, it's not *always* a sign of bad design. There are very few absolutes in "soft" things like "good" or "bad" design. Nevertheless, it does often indicate a different approach would be preferable, for one or more of these reasons: extensibility, ease of maintenance, familiarity, and similar.

In your particular case: One of the standard ways to make arbitrary class-specific processing possible without type switches or bloating/polluting the interface of the class is to use the [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). You create a generic `MessageVisitor` interface, teach the `Message` subclasses to call into it, and implement it wherever you need to process them:

```
class MessageVisitor;

class Message
{
public:
    virtual ~Message(){};

    virtual void accept(MessageVisitor &visitor) = 0;
};

class ObjectTypeA : public Message
{
  void accept(MessageVisitor &visitor) override
  { visitor.visit(*this); }
/*...*/
};

class ObjectTypeB : public Message
{
  void accept(MessageVisitor &visitor) override
  { visitor.visit(*this); }
/*...*/
};

class ObjectTypeC : public Message
{
  void accept(MessageVisitor &visitor) override
  { visitor.visit(*this); }
/*...*/
};

class MessageVisitor
{
public:
  virtual void visit(ObjectTypeA &subject) {}

  virtual void visit(ObjectTypeB &subject) {}

  virtual void visit(ObjectTypeC &subject) {}
};
```

You would then use it like this:

```
void doWork()
{
    struct DoWorkMessageVisitor : MessageVisitor
    {
      void visit(ObjectTypeA &subject) override { doSomethingA(subject); }

      void visit(ObjectTypeB &subject) override { doSomethingB(subject); }

      void visit(ObjectTypeC &subject) override { doSomethingC(subject); }
    };
    std::string line;
    while(getLine(line))
    {
        std::shared_ptr<Message> object=parseLine(line);
        DoWorkMessageVisitor v;
        object->accept(v);
    }
}
```

Feel free to customise this with `const` overloads etc. as necessary.

Note that `accept` cannot be implemented in the base class, because you need the correct type of `*this` in the invocation of `visit`. *That* is where the type switch has "moved".

---

An alternative is to make the `visit` functions in `MessageVisitor` pure virtual instead of empty. Then, if you need to add a new message type, it will automatically force you to update all places where such type-specific processing occurs.

Comment: Hmm, so this seems to be equivalent to my code, but avoids explicit checking of type. But can you name some advantages of this approach over my code? How is it more maintainable/extensible/whatever?

Comment: @Ruslan First off, it's familiar - "Visitor" is pretty standard terminology, so when someone looks at the class interface, it will be obvious to them how it works. The visitor classes can also be shared, derived from etc. Also, is `doWork` the only place in code where you will *now* and *forever* want to do such a type switch? If not, then adding a new derived class means either going through all such places and updating them (hoping you don't miss any), or adding a new `visit` as pure virtual and having the compiler tell you where such occurences are. I will add this bit to the answer.

Comment: Yes, indeed there will be multiple users of the parser, not only `doWork`.

Answer (score 3):

You're really asking for opinions on whats *good* and *bad* design. Here's mine:

Yours is *bad* design, because you try to do something in another class that should be handled by the subclasses, because that's what polymorphism is for.

Your mother class should have a

```
virtual void do_stuff_that_is_specific_to_the_subclass(...) = 0;
```

method, which you'd implement in your subclasses.

> Here the parser would be a library function, and the objects don't know in advance how they will be processed. So, I can't put the processing code to a virtual function of Message implementations.

Why not? You should simply have a

```
virtual void do_stuff_that_is_specific_to_the_subclass(parser&, ...) = 0;
```

method that uses the parser differently for each subclass. There's no reason that what you can do in your `if/else` clauses couldn't just be done in the subclasses, unless it breaks encapsulation, which I'd doubt, because the only reason you've got these objects is that you want to do specific things differently for different lines.

Comment: See update, the objects don't know in advance how they will be processed by callers of parser, which is a library routine.

Comment: I don't quite see how this would be done when there are multiple users of parser. In this case there should a separate virtual function for each user, right?

Comment: I don't really understand your question, but, no, as far as I can tell from your original Q, there shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

`doSomethingA`, `doCompletelyUnrelatedProcessing` and `doSomethingEvenMoreDifferent` could be just overrides of pure virtual function of Message class. In your case that would be much more effecient and better as a design solution.