# c++ Is there something like typeof(Foo)

Tags: c++, reflection

I'm having a Class called `User`.

I would like to write a function which gets me all entries of the table User from db like this:

```
getObectList(type aType)
{
...
select * from aType.name
...
}
```

and call it like `getObjectList(typeof(User))`

Is something like this possible in c++?

Comment: yes. a template will do this for you as long as each type of aType has a method called name() that returns a string containing the table name.

Comment: The 3rd answer down (not the accepted one) on this question does what you want I believe
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351845/finding-the-type-of-an-object-in-c

Comment: You're trying to do something _very_ inflexible: I doubt it's a good idea. Why not call it like `getObjectList(user_table)` where `user_table` is a string (or some object representing a table)?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out `<typeinfo>` header, there are some methods there which might be able to help you.

Example:

```
#include <typeinfo>

class Foo { };

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    string s = typeid(foo).name();
}
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/6G2iEp)

**Have in mind, that output may differ when you use other compilers etc. since it's implementation-detail how to implement naming for types.**

To circumvent this, you coul do some testing at initialization for used types and store results of `name()` or `hash_code()` methods of used types and then just check it at runtime. This way you get compiler-independent solution.

Answer (score -1):

typeof (expression) is an extension provided by gcc and Clang. It is exactly the same as using the type itself, so if you write

```
int x;
typeof (x) y;
```

the second declaration is exactly the same as writing int y. typeof will never have any effect at runtime; the type it returns is always determined at compile time.

You cannot pass a type to a function. Whether you type it directly or by using typeof () doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Its much better to use decltype, which is standard in C++11, not some extensions in specific compiler. Though i think it's not what author wanted.