# How to return elements of a given type from a vector?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, rtti, dynamic-cast

I have a class, `EscapeRoomWrapper`, and two classes which are derived from it, `ScaryRoom` and `KidsRoom`.

In another class, `Company`, I added a `vector` of pointers to all the room objects (`EscapeRoomWrapper`, `ScaryRoom`, and `KidsRoom`). I want to write a function in the `Company` class where I give it a type of room and it should return all of the rooms of that type that exist in the `vector` of all rooms.

I thought about using `typeid`, but the professer banned us from using it. My last idea is to use `dynamic_cast`.

```
typedef enum{
    SCARY_ROOM, KIDS_ROOM, BASE_ROOM
}RoomType;

class Company{
    string CompanyName;
    std::vector<EscapeRoomWrapper*> Rooms;

public:
    std::vector<EscapeRoomWrapper*>& getAllRoomsByType(RoomType type) const;
};

class EscapeRoomWrapper{
    EscapeRoom room;
    std::vector<Enigma> Enigmas;
public:
    // functions here
};

class ScaryRoom : public EscapeRoomWrapper {
private:
    int ageLimit;
    int NumOfScaryEnigmas;
public:
    // functions for escary room
};

class KidsRoom : public EscapeRoomWrapper {
private:
    int ageLimit;
public:
    // functions for kidsroom
};
```

Any ideas of how I can Implement this function?

```
std::vector<EscapeRoomWrapper*>& getAllRoomsByType(RoomType type) const
```

Comment: To jasmin, Sorry, I cancel your edit my bad.

Comment: it is ok thanks fo the edit

Comment: You could create an enum of all the types you have and assign one to each class and select that way. It's cheaper than a string compare. *shrug*

Comment: ok so i added enum

Comment: now i want to add for each room the write type

Comment: but i still don't get it how i can find the set of all rooms based on the types with dynamic cast

Comment: so should i run on the vector of rooms and each time check if the room type is simelar ro the given type the a make a new set and each time i found a room add it to the set and lastly return the set ?

Comment: is this a good idea to make a new set and fill it whith the rooms ?

Comment: whether or not the cast works is what tells you what type the rooms are.

Comment: If you cant use `typeid` (and you should not), then `dynamic_cast` is the way to go. But most c++ developers will pull a funny face when `dynamic_cast` is mentioned. Firstly it's a very definitely a performance hit. The other reason is that its presence is very often an indicator of poor design. Often times the better option is to have a method on the base class, which is implemented in the child and does whatever you need to do without the caller needing to know the concrete type.

Comment: May be your needed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351845/finding-the-type-of-an-object-in-c

Comment: thank    you .....

Comment: didn't help i didn't get it at all how can i use dynamic cast and how would i know the type of each room basem on the enum ? should i add another variable to the room ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track by thinking you can use `dynamic_cast`, eg:

```
class Company {
    ...
    std::vector<EscapeRoomWrapper*> Rooms;
public:
    std::vector<EscapeRoomWrapper*> getAllRoomsByType(RoomType type) const;
};

std::vector<EscapeRoomWrapper*> Company::getAllRoomsByType(RoomType type) const
{
    std::vector<EscapeRoomWrapper*> result;

    switch (type) {
        case SCARY_ROOM:
            for (size_t i = 0; i < Rooms.size(); ++i) {
                if (dynamic_cast<ScaryRoom*>(Rooms[i])) {
                    result.push_back(Rooms[i]);
                }
            } 
            break;

        case KIDS_ROOM:
            for (size_t i = 0; i < Rooms.size(); ++i) {
                if (dynamic_cast<KidsRoom*>(Rooms[i])) {
                    result.push_back(Rooms[i]);
                }
            } 
            break;

        case BASE_ROOM:
            result = Rooms;
            break;
    }

    return result;
}
```

But, `dynamic_cast` has some runtime overhead, and it depends on the compiler producing RTTI for the classes (which it does by default, but that *can* be disabled).  There are other solutions available.

You could define a virtual function to have each class report its type from the `enum` and then you can look at those type values:

```
class EscapeRoomWrapper {
    ...
public:
    ...
    virtual RoomType getRoomType() const { return BASE_ROOM; }
};

class ScaryRoom : public EscapeRoomWrapper {
    ... 
public:
    ...
    RoomType getRoomType() const { return SCARY_ROOM; }
};

class KidsRoom : public EscapeRoomWrapper {
    ... 
public:
    ...
    RoomType getRoomType() const { return KIDS_ROOM; }
};

std::vector<EscapeRoomWrapper*> Company::getAllRoomsByType(RoomType type) const
{
    std::vector<EscapeRoomWrapper*> result;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < Rooms.size(); ++i) {
        if ((Rooms[i]->getRoomType() == type) || (type == BASE_ROOM)) {
            result.push_back(Rooms[i]);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Or, you could just store separate lists for each room type:

```
class Company {
    ...
    std::vector<EscapeRoomWrapper*> ScaryRooms;
    std::vector<EscapeRoomWrapper*> KidsRooms;
    std::vector<EscapeRoomWrapper*> AllRooms;
public:
    std::vector<EscapeRoomWrapper*> getAllRoomsByType(RoomType type) const;
};

std::vector<EscapeRoomWrapper*> Company::getAllRoomsByType(RoomType type) const
{
    switch (type) {
        case SCARY_ROOM:
            return ScaryRooms;

        case KIDS_ROOM:
            return KidsRooms;

        case BASE_ROOM:
            return AllRooms;
    }

    return std::vector<EscapeRoomWrapper*>();
}
```